# Writable List type custom control property in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, typeconverter, customproperty

I am using a typeconverter to make my customized property of combobox as list type during design-time. I am doing it in VB.net. I have implemented like this:

```
<TypeConverter(GetType(DropDownConverter))>
```

It is working fine but it become selectable only during design-time, can not write. But I also sometime need to write on this property during design-time. I can not do it. Can I get help in this regard? Thanks.

Comment: So, you have a custom Property of a Custom Control that represents a List of something that is read-only, while you want it read/write, at design-time. Post a piece of code related to the Property, the code of your TypeConverter and a description of what it's meant to accomplish + (important) the UI Platform <- add the relevant Tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jimi. I could solve the issue. Actually, I was also thinking that the answer should be inside the converter. But at the beginning, I couldn't find it. But later on I found that. 

Public Overloads Overrides Function GetStandardValuesExclusive(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext) As Boolean
        Return False
        'ORIGINALY IT WAS TRUE; CHANGED TO FALSE ON 10-04-21
        ' True makes the Combobox only selectable
        ' False also allows free input
    End Function

Anyway thank Jimi again.

Bye.